# Is it possilble to GET message by sender email address on outlook mail api

Tags: outlook-restapi

I am getting messages from my inbox, using Outlook Mail API

I can request a specific message by message id, however is it possible to request by a certain sender email address, if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to do it....
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparameters

Using **$filter=From/EmailAddress/Address eq 'hr@contoso.com'** , filters out the emails from the specified sender